# Launch process that needs to trigger UAC in netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I often need to launch external processes so I wrote a convenient method to easily do that. One of these processes needs to trigger UAC in order to ask the user for their permission. I did some research and found that setting the `Verb` property of the `ProcessStartInfo` object to `runas` in addition to setting the `UseShellExecute` to `true` should do the trick.

```
private static void StartProcess(string fileName, string arguments, bool elevated)
{
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = arguments,
        FileName = fileName
    };

    if (elevated) 
    {
        start.Verb = "runas";
        start.UseShellExecute = true;
    }

    int exitCode = 0;
    using (var proc = new Process { StartInfo = start })
    {
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    }

    if (exitCode != 0)
    {
        var message = string.Format(
            "Error {0} executing {1} {2}",
            exitCode,
            start.FileName,
            start.Arguments);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
    }
}
```

However, the `Verb` property is not available in `netcore` therefore I can't figure out how to achieve the same result. Any suggestion?

Comment: You may be aware of this but just thought of sharing again - **both Verb as well as Verbs are coming back as part of .NET Standard 2.0** Refer this - https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/1103

Comment: @Sanket thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware. I'll wait for netstandard 2.0. In the mean time, any known workarounds?

Comment: I am not aware of any workaround.

Comment: @Sanket if you post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: I would suggest you to wait for few days... may be someone will post some workaround.